# Checking the owner field of struct mutex in Linux

Tags: c, linux-kernel, mutex

I would like to check in a `struct mutex` which is locked in the kernel, who is the owner of that mutex.

```
struct mutex {
    atomic_long_t       owner;
    spinlock_t      wait_lock;
#ifdef CONFIG_MUTEX_SPIN_ON_OWNER
    struct optimistic_spin_queue osq; /* Spinner MCS lock */
#endif
    struct list_head    wait_list;
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES
    void            *magic;
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC
    struct lockdep_map  dep_map;
#endif
};
```

I understand from the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/locking/mutex-design.html) that:

> Field owner actually contains struct task_struct * to the current lock
>   owner and it is therefore NULL if not currently owned.

Is there any safe way to compare that field to `current`?

Comment: N.B.: From [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-locking/locks.html): *Neither type of lock is recursive*

Comment: @red0ct I am not trying to implement a recursive lock, I wanted to implement some clean up code that makes sure that a process killed while holding a mutex releases it (i.e. taking some corrective actions in case of process release while holding a mutex)

Comment: @ad3angel1s Can't you just set a flag when you have acquired the mutex, clear the flag when you have released the mutex, and check the flag in your clean-up code?

Comment: @IanAbbott not sure how would that work. How would i know during clean up that the current process is the actual owner of the mutex by just looking at the `isTaken` flag?

Comment: @ad3angel1s Because the code that is locking the mutex should also be responsible for unlocking it.

Comment: @IanAbbott the whole point is that I am trying to write a clean up code in case the process that holds the mutex is killed before reaching the unlock. In this clean up code, if I just check for a flag without indication of the ownership of the mutex, I can't know if I am the process owning the mutex or if it is just a normal release.

Comment: @ad3angel1s If you have a task that can be killed and removed while holding a mutex, it sounds like you have deeper problems. Only the task that locked the mutex can unlock it. Perhaps the code is doing something forbidden such as returning to user mode while holding a lock?

Comment: @IanAbbott it's a user task, users can kill it while holding the mutex. As only the task that locks the mutex can unlock it, I want to make sure that same task unlocks it before death.

Comment: @ad3angel1s A user task should only hold a kernel lock (such as a `struct mutex`) while it is in kernel mode. It should be released before returning to user mode. It sounds like you are trying to use it to do something outside its legitimate usage.

Comment: @IanAbbott not sure where I am not being clear here, the user task gets the mutex in kernel mode (i.e. in a system call), but I want to find a way so that if the task is killed in kernel mode while holding the mutex, it releases the resources it has (i.e. the mutex). It's my understanding that this wouldn't happen automatically.

Comment: @ad3angel1s It depends what you mean by "killed". The task may get signalled, but it won't get destroyed in the middle of a system call.

Comment: Suppose it receives a kill signal while holding the mutex. What is going to happen? Does the kernel assures that the system call gets completed (i.e. it reaches the natural unlock) before removing the task?

Comment: @ad3angel1s It depends what state it is in when the signal is delivered. If it is TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE, nothing will happen. If it is TASK_KILLABLE, it will be woken by certain signals. If it is TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE, if will be woken by unmasked signals. If it is TASK_RUNNING, well it is already awake. If it gets woken, it can call `signal_pending()` to check for any pending signal and take appropriate action (such as cleaning up and returning early from whatever it was doing, perhaps with an `-ERESTARTSYS` error).

Comment: my problem would be if it's in TASK_RUNNING while holding the mutex. I am already covering the others states (especially TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE). Still don't understand what will happen when my task is in TASK_RUNNING, holding the mutex and it gets a kill signal. I understand that the release function will be called eventually (as the system call has opened a device file where it has got the mutex).

Comment: @ad3angel1s If it's holding the mutex, it should be currently handling a system call (since a mutex should only be held while the task is in kernel mode). If it is in the TASK_RUNNING state, it will be unaware of the signal unless it does something that checks for pending signals. Ideally, it should check for pending signals before entering an uninterruptible state. I'm not sure why you mentioned the release file handler. Yes, it might be called as a direct result of a process being killed, but is not necessarily called by any tasks associated with that process.

Comment: Yes, it's holding the mutex in the system call. So, I understand from your comment that in TASK_RUNNING state and during the system call, any signal will not have any effect on it until it exits the system call, and at that point it would have already naturally released the mutex. So this check in the release function is not needed. Still don't understand your last comment: "but is not necessarily called by any tasks associated with that process." wouldn't that happen in process context? Last question, is there any documentation I can read about what you explained in your latest comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to compare that field to current?

From [kernel/locking/mutex.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/locking/mutex.c#L73) you can use this function:

```
/*
 * Internal helper function; C doesn't allow us to hide it :/
 *
 * DO NOT USE (outside of mutex code).
 */
static inline struct task_struct *__mutex_owner(struct mutex *lock)
{
    return (struct task_struct *)(atomic_long_read(&lock->owner) & ~MUTEX_FLAGS);
}
```

I guess then:

```
extern struct mutex *some_mutex;
extern struct task_struct *current;
__mutex_owner(some_mutex) == current;
```

Comment: Thanks! but why the "DO NOT USE (outside of mutex code)" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement recursive mutex, then you may use [mutex_trylock_recursive](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10.17/source/include/linux/mutex.h#L215) function: it behaves similar to `mutex_trylock`, but it is allowed to call this function by the mutex's current owner. In that case it returns a special value.

---

Like `__mutex_owner`, the function `mutex_trylock_recursive` is marked as deprecated/"do not use". Probably, someone doesn't like an idea about recursive mutexes in the kernel.